# Jumps in firewall rule sets

Tags: firewall, iptables

I have a general question regarding software-based firewalls.
Specifically, I would like to know whether there are other firewalls than iptables
which allow the specification of jumps inside of the rule set.

In iptables, users have the possibility to specify "jumps" inside of the rule set by targeting specific chains when a rule matches on a packet.

For example, in the following rule set

```
(1) iptables -A INPUT --src 1.2.3.4 -j ACCEPT
(2) iptables -A INPUT --src 1.2.3.5 -j ACCEPT
(3) iptables -A INPUT --src 1.2.3.6 -j ACCEPT
(4) iptables -A INPUT --src 8.8.8.8 -j NEXT_CHAIN
(5) iptables -A INPUT --src 2.2.2.2 -j ACCEPT
(6) iptables -A INPUT --src 2.2.2.3 -j ACCEPT

<NEXT_CHAIN starts here ...>
```

rule (4) redirects packet processing to another rule set named "NEXT_CHAIN".
In other words, rules (5) and (6) are skipped (in some sense, if there is a match in NEXT_CHAIN). 
I think this is also possible in iptables' predecessor ipchains.

Do you know whether there are any other firewalls that provide a similar feature?

Comment: Rules 5 and 6 are not skipped.  If there are no accepts in the chain, it comes back to this tables and completes 5 and 6.

Comment: Dear downvoter, if you do not like the way I asked the question, please tell me so I can improve the question, instead of just anonymously voting down the post ...

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but I upvoted it to cancel them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research on other packet filtering systems, and I found out the following:

- OpenBSD's pf can implement some sort of control using conditional anchors:

  EXAMPLE: anchor udp-only in on fxp0 inet proto udp
- The OpenFlow switch provides direct jumps by using GOTO targets
- NetBSD's ipfw provides the skipto  action

Each of these features allows to modify the control flow during packet classification and can be used to implement JUMP semantics.

Answer (score 1):

The other main competitor to iptables is pf, which has similar capabilities to iptables.

Comment: I am not sure whether this is possible in pf, could you sketch a brief example (similar to the above one), how such a behaviour could be achieved? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Linux** firewalls are built around **Netfilter**; the kernel's network packet processing framework which is made of several kernel modules performing specific tasks like:

1. The FILTER module (always loaded by default) mainly allows us to ACCEPT or DROP IP packets based on a certain matching criteria.
2. The NAT module set allows us to perform Network Address Translations (SNAT, DNAT, MASQUERADE).
3. The MANGLE module allows us to alter certain IP packet fields (TOS, TTL)

Users configure the Netfilter framework ("kernel mode") to suit their firewall needs using **iptables** which is an "userland" application run from the command line. With iptables we define rules that instruct the Linux kernel what to do with IP packets when they arrive into, pass through, or leave our Linux box.

All the Linux based firewalls are based in Netfilter and most of them use iptables as a way to control Netfilter.

Different technologies use a similar strategy; i.e. in BSD (OpenBSD) the kernel module is called PF (Packet Filter) an the "userland" application for controlling **PF** is called **pfctl**

Depending what technology you use you have one or the other; both systems do basically the same and of course they both can perform the jumps you mention. Remember a firewall in Linux or BSD is just a set of rules loaded by the corresponding userland application which set the behavior of the corresponding net traffic control kernel engine.

also consider when you jump into a user defined chain you can also "return"

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I understand that the netfilter/pf kernel modules can be used to implement firewalling functionality.
But my question was a bit in the other direction: do you know whether there are other existing firewalls than iptables which allow the user to specify jumps in the rule set?

Comment: Please re-read my answer slowly; iptables is not a firewall. The "key functionality" of a firewall is implemented within certain OS kernel modules. Then there are no firewalls in the Linux/BSD world re-implementing their own kernel modules for doing what the OS already does very well. On the other hand iptables and pfctl are just "userland" applications used to "control" those kernels modules. You could have some firewall re-implementing the functionality of those control applications within its own code but I'm not aware of anyone really pursuing this approach.